# drag and drop using jquery full calendar

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

I am trying to replicate drag and drop functionality using Jquery Fullcalendar plugin from below link -

https://salesforceprojects.quora.com/Implement-full-calendar-drag-and-drop-in-Visualforce-page

I am unable to update the dates as i am getting error at line no 99

> Error -
>
> ```
> Error: missing ) after argurment list
>
> setEvnt(Indonesian Cyber Freedom :: ~.\,event.start.format(),event.end.format());
> ```

I believe here we are trying to pass `id` to `setEvnt`. If so how to pass id from vf page to apex class by action function.

Regards

Comment: Just a note that drag and drop calendar is coming native in lightning, maybe in spring release if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Indonesian Cyber Freedom :: ~.\" seems like random text. From the code, it looks like it should be:

```
setEvnt(event.id, event.start.format(), event.end.format());
```

It's probably a copy-paste error in the post.

Comment: If i put a quotes into it and try , it throws an error invalid id - Indonesian Cyber Freedom :: ~.\\. Can you please check how to pass id

Comment: @Sid I missed that part, apparently (it didn't really make much sense). Try my latest edit.